# Force named a file aux.txt (prohibited file name) via Git Bash on Windows, cannot delete the file (or do anything to it)

Tags: windows, filesystems

I was intrigued by the fact that Windows had prohibited file names, and as such Windows will not allow you to name the file any of these prohibited names.

However, I was feeling cheeky and was working on Git Bash and the idea popped into my head: I can just do

```
touch aux.txt
```

and I will have bypassed this prohibition.

Now I regret my cheekiness and am stuck with an aux.txt file that I cannot do anything with. I have run into the issue of trying to delete a file that did not exist before, but I think that this is a special case.

I tried to rename it, but that seemed to only make things worse. If I rename it to something else, it says it does not exist. If I try to leave it as aux.txt, it says that the name is invalid.

As you probably have figured out, error messages come up any time I click anywhere on my desktop (where the file is located) and the name of the file is stuck highlighted in blue awaiting a valid rename, which is impossible.

I seem to have dug myself into a funny little hole in the Windows OS.

Comment: What is the actual extension? .txt is a valid one. What are the error messages exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't consider the simple solution of deleting the file in the way that I created it.

Simply did `rm aux.txt` in Git Bash and the file was gone with the wind.