# Windows Unable to delete file with reserved name

Tags: windows, file-management

I git-cloned a repo for Linux divers(ath10k) having files named `aux.h` and `aux.c`.

Quoting the answer [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unable-to-rename-a-folder-to-com-errorthe/ff48c793-ab97-4881-952a-df195321c11c),

> MS-DOS Device Driver names cannot be used as file names in Windows. As
> a result, we are unable to name folders as con, aux, nul, etc.

Now I am stuck with those files and cannot delete them.

System:

```
Windows 10 Home  
Version 21H2  
OS build 19044.1645
```

Already tried (*all commands executed with admin privileges*):

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cant-delete-file-could-not-find-this-file-please/354fa74a-1d11-4acc-9fba-4128ca971e6c
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/cannot-delete-file-says-item-not-found-could-not/54d74f22-695d-4be3-8639-12f268680b00
- rm `aux.h`
- rmdir /S /Q `Ath10k`(the root directory)
- [Force named a file aux.txt (prohibited file name) via Git Bash on Windows, cannot delete the file (or do anything to it)](https://superuser.com/q/1581606/859609)

Comment: Have you tried using a privileged command prompt to delete it?

Comment: Try a different Admin User (make one) and try Unlocker 1.92 (MajorGeeks)

Comment: Try these two solutions : 1: command (as admin) `del \\%computername%\c$\Users\Your_Path\aux`  2 : Run bash with WSL, then you can use `rm aux`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had initially deleted the folder using Windows Explorer. But the files remained. Tried cmd after that, failed again.

Here's what **finally** did the job (*should have thought of this earlier*):

1. Opened Git Bash.
2. Went to the local repository's parent directory.
3. Typed `rm -rf Ath10k` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The ability of bash to bypass Windows restrictions seems concerning, though. Why was it even allowed?

Considering the fact that the files could not be opened on Windows,
the cloning process should have failed cleanly instead of creating problems further down the line.

Comment: Those are not deliberate restrictions in the security sense. They are *special cases* where certain names are "rerouted" to have a different purpose. It's a carry-over from DOS era that the NT kernel doesn't have (devices have a separate namespace), just emulates it for old apps and users, so you're only bypassing that emulation. It's a bit like how Bash on Linux has special handling for /dev/tcp but that doesn't affect non-Bash programs.

Comment: @user1686 Thank you for the explanation.